# Table Row two Background Using PHP Function

Tags: php, background, rows

I have This Function For Two backgrounds row of table :

```
function background() {
      $bg = ''; // odd 
      $bg2 = 'F3F3F3'; // even

      if ( $i%2 == 0 )
       $bgs = "$bg";
      else
       $bgs = "$bg2";
 }
```

PHP CODE IS :

```
echo "<TABLE>";
$i = 0;
while ($f = $db->fetcharray( $r )) // for fetch 
{
background(); // function
echo "<tr> 
                 <td bgcolor=\"{$bgs}\">1</td>
                 <td bgcolor=\"{$bgs}\">any name</td>
                 <td bgcolor=\"{$bgs}\">any date</td>
         </tr> ";
$i++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

HTML OUTPUT IS :

```
<Table>
<TR>
<td bgcolor="">$id</td>
<td bgcolor="">$name</td>
<td bgcolor="">$date</td>
</TR>
</table>
```

But This Not Worked. ( not show Background Color ) What's Problem ?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you didn't explain the issue

Comment: My problem is very clear. i dont care what's your mean ! my<td> not show background ! just this

Comment: @Saimon Avazian: 1. calm down 2. have you seen the generated html? Would you be so kind to post it here 3. You need to read how function work and what is [variables scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) - your `function background` makes no sense

Comment: the problem is the # missing in front of your color

Answer (score 2):

You define local scope variables inside `background` function and they are not available outside of it. Also inside you cant use `$i` variable from outside scope. So you should make your function return values:

```
function background($i) {
    return $i % 2 == 0 ? '' : '#F3F3F3';
}
```

And use it:

```
...
$bgs = background($i);
echo "<tr> 
    <td bgcolor=\"{$bgs}\">$id</td>
    <td bgcolor=\"{$bgs}\">$name</td>
    <td bgcolor=\"{$bgs}\">$date</td>
</tr> ";
...
```